# Проект Эйлера. Задача 106. Суммы особых подмножеств: мета-проверка

Tags: python, алгоритм

> Пусть S(A) представляет собой сумму элементов множества А размером n. Будем называть это множество особым суммарным множеством, если для любых двух непустых и непересекающихся подмножеств B и C справедливо следующее:
>
> S(B) ≠ S(C); т.е. суммы элементов подмножеств не могут быть равными.
>   Если B содержит больше элементов, чем C, то S(B) > S(C).
>   Для этой задачи предположим, что данное множество состоит из n строго возрастающих элементов и оно уже соответствует второму правилу.
>
> К удивлению, из 25 возможных пар подмножеств, которые можно получить из множества при n = 4, лишь одну из них надо проверить на равенство (первое условие). Подобным образом, при n = 7, лишь 70 из 966 пар подмножеств надо проверить на равенство.
>
> Сколько пар подмножеств необходимо проверить на равенство из общего числа 261625 пар, которые можно образовать при n = 12?
>
> Примечание: Данная задача имеет также отношение к задачам №103 и №105.

Вот некоторые особые множества для первых начальных n:

n = 1: {1}

n = 2: {1, 2}

n = 3: {2, 3, 4}

n = 4: {3, 5, 6, 7}

n = 5: {6, 9, 11, 12, 13}

Мой вопрос в следующем. Для n=4, действительно, есть 25 возможных уникальных пар непустых множеств. С этим согласен. Я не понимаю, почему проверить на 1 условие надо только одну.

Если я верно мыслю, то выполнение второго условия проверяется только для случая, когда размеры множеств отличны. Если второе условие выполняется, то проверка 1 условия пройдена автоматически. Это очевидно.

Однако если отсеять из 25 вариантов пары равного размера, то получается никак не 1 пара, а 9. Почему для n=4 в задаче проверяется на равенство только 1 пара?!

На всякий случай приведу свой код поиска пар подмножеств:

```
import itertools

a = [3, 5, 6, 7]

combinations = set()
pair_combinations = list()

for b in range(1, len(a)):
    combinations.update(itertools.combinations(a, b))


combinations = list(combinations)
combinations.sort()
num = 0

for b in combinations:
    b_ = list(combinations)
    b_.remove(b)
    for с in b_:
        sum_b = sum(b)
        sum_c = sum(с)
        len_set_b = len(list(b))
        len_set_c = len(list(с))

        set_b = set(b)
        set_c = set(с)

        # определяем непересекающиеся подмножества и проводим над ними проверку по условию
        if set_b.isdisjoint(set_c):
            # проверка, чтобы не дублировать пары
            if [с, b] not in pair_combinations:
                # if len_set_b == len_set_c:
                pair_combinations.append([b, с])

num = 0
for pair in pair_combinations:
    print(num, pair)
    num = num + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть

```
A = {a, b, c, d}
```

Известно, что последовательность строго возрастающая:

```
a < b < c < d
```

Также исходя из соответствия второму правилу, известно, что сумма любого большего подмножества больше любого меньшего:

```
a + b > c
a + b > d
...
b + c + d > a
```

Остается доказать первое правило, т.е. неравенство подмножеств одинакового размера:

```
a + b != c + d
a + c != b + d
a + d != b + c
```

Первый случай верен автоматически, потому, что каждое слагаемое из правой части больше каждого из левой, значит и сумма больше

```
a + b < c + d
```

Cо вторым так же, потому, что `b > a` и `d > c`, значит

```
a + c < b + d
```

а вот третий случай нужно проверить, потому, что хоть `b > a`, но `c > d`

Comment: А вот это очень интересная мысль. Благодарю. Надо подумать, как ее отмасштабировать на автомате.

Comment: @АлександрРядинских существует чисто математическое решение без циклов (если не считать сумму и факториал). Но даже с помощью `combinations` с отфильтровкой лишних последовательностей можно решить задачу для `n=12`за разумное время. Вы, насколько я понимаю, не за решением сюда пришли, его наверняка и нагуглить можно, так что выкладывать рабочий код я не буду, но той информации что я дал должно хватить для реализации хотя бы неоптимального решения.